# Can't reach my spring boot app in aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am beginner and I have launched my spring boot app (Using jar file) on my aws instance on port 8080. But I am not able to access it through my browser (PublicDNS:8080) which shows 'This site can’t be reached - took too long to respond'.

I have allowed all http and https traffic from anywhere to my server and to port 8080. Please help.

$curl http://localhost:8080 from my AMI gives StatusCode : 200. But curl http://PublicDNS from my local machine gives

```
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
 eption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I have attached the screenshot of my Security group inbound rules below

[Security group inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFvlf.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

on your ec2 instance try $curl http://localhost:8080  [ instead of curl u can use wget also] if it works fine; u know your spring boot is fine and problem is in security group. If it does not work ; problem is in your spring boot .

I feel your security group looks good; its a problem in your spring boot.

Comment: $curl http://localhost:8080 gives StatusCode : 200. But curl http://publicDNS from my local machine gives  'curl : Unable to connect to the remote server' , it will be successful but  I have worked with my spring boot app on my local machine and it worked fine and still is. I have no idea what's going wrong.